# Are STUN TURN servers not reliable

Tags: webrtc

I am using the google's TURN servers which is given in the demo, Sometimes the connection is established and remote video is streamed sometimes I just get a black screen instead of remote stream. Are these servers not reliable or is there any other issue because I can see the IP of the other machine on the peer which means the peer connection has been established. So what could be the possible problem is?

Answer (score 0):

google doesn't provide any TURN server, only a STUN one.

There's a lot of situation where you need a TURN server, but as far as I know, there's no open TURN server. Even when the ip is detected, you can have problems with a proxy destroying the UDP stream or some of the ports needed.